# unable to install an old NVIDIA driver in Lubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, lubuntu, nouveau

I have a PC equipped with NVIDIA GeForce 7200 GS / 7300 SE and running Lubuntu 20.04.

Recently after immigrating to Lubuntu, NVIDIA started a lot of problems like the screen somehow started to blink or sometimes everything freezes (even mouse/keyboard stop working) and the only way out of it is hard reboot.

As far as I know, Lubuntu by default uses `nouveau` as graphic driver and when I disabled `nouveau` (using `nouveau.modeset=0` in the grub) apparently all those problems are gone.

```
lspci -k|grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'01:00.0
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G72 [GeForce 7200 GS / 7300 SE] (rev a1) Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. G72 [GeForce 7200 GS / 7300 SE]                                
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

Now I think there is no `nouveau` neither any other driver because 7200 GS/7300 SE is unsupported and I wasn't able to install any appropriate driver in any possible way. What should I do now? With no driver, can I still use the vga for stuffs like watching HQ movies or playing games as I used to in Win 7?

UPDATE: can't leave it that way; Lubuntu won't start and using the recovery mode I was able to login back. Need a solution!

Comment: The parameter you gave at `grub` prevented the kernel from loading & using `nouveau` at that stage of the booing process, however it's likely that `nouveau` was loaded later in the boot process anyway (thus the listing in your `lspci` command) as it wasn't blacklisted. If you blacklist `nouveau` you'll likely end up with no video at all.  I had issues with some nvidia cards, as the boxes were old (& x86/i386), and the issues only occurred at kernels 5.3 or newer, I was happy to keep those boxes on 4.15 or 18.04's GA kernel.

Comment: It might also help if you clarify things. You mention *blink*, the blinking I experienced was at `sddm` only (ie. login screen) with 5.3 kernel or higher, freezing issues not on nvidia so I'd explore your hardware for that one.. You mention no keyboard/mouse, did SysRq keys allow reboot? shutdown? etc or was the kernel locked up & didn't respond?

Comment: @guiverc The blinking was like yours, only in login screen. And by freeze I mean absolutely no response at all for example I can't even turn the keyboards numlock on/off. After a lot of googling I thought an older kernel might help so asked about it https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300348/ubuntu-10-04-kernel-for-20-04

Comment: Your issue is recorded here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1895905  I don't know why but it first appeared in *eoan* and occurs on 5.3 & later kernels. I would **not** use a 10.04 kernel (unless you're offline; even then I'd likely not, I never had the issue with 5.0/disco or earlier kernels); the issue isn't `sddm` though; it's where it shows.  Did you try SysRq commands to ask the kernel to reboot, safely `umount` or shutdown?  Using those is a clue as to kernel state (the kernel will respond if running & Sysrq wasn't disabled; if it doesn't respond you have a big clue)

Comment: If you're not aware of the SysRq commands, I'd suggest using your phone to search for "*magic sysrq*" as usually the wikipedia page is first search result, and that page is as good as any to refresh you on what commands you need (eg. REISUB)   If your system won't start; I'd not try and start it, but instead boot *live* media & explore your system... is the disk healthy? (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) and likely memtest & check your hardware.. I'd test it firstly with a *live* system, **then** `fsck` or file-system check to look for errors.. if found you may find it boots

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for your time. I reinstalled Lubuntu 20.04 with the hope that it might help solving the issue, however it freezed again and this SysRq way of commanding didn't respond at all, like nothing happens (maybe because as I mentioned before the keyboard doesn't work). One thing I noticed is that the freeze happened while I was using GParted in Lubuntu. Since GParted is not native LXQT, it could cause the problem although once before during the updating process with Lubuntu tool the whole PC freezed too.

Comment: @guiverc One more bothering thing is that I have an annoying disorder in some application's user interface. So far every browser I tested - except firefox - suffer from this disorder of UI. The picture I provided here is from how Chrome looks like: https://postimg.cc/VdPrY0FT

Comment: UPDATE ON CHROME: Problem solved by turning off "Hardware Acceleration" in its settings.