# ubuntu 10.04 kernel for 20.04

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, kernel, lubuntu, 10.04

Is it possible to install Ubuntu 10.04's kernel in Lubuntu 20.04 and use it as the default one? If so can anyone please explain it in the easiest step-by-step way? I'm not a pro!

Because of my old, unsupported and trouble-maker Nvidia VGA (which made the PC absolutely unusable) I have to either install and old Ubuntu, like 10.04 or go for Windows 7. This is actually my last shot before Ubuntu 10.04 fresh install.

UPDATE I: Previously I mentioned the problem **[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300031/unable-to-install-an-old-nvidia-driver-in-lubuntu)**  but as I did some google I found that there is no secure way to deal with the issue except a fresh install of an older Ubuntu (or an older kernel) which can support the VGA.

Comment: It is a bad idea and unlikely that it will work. You'd better explain what is the Nvidia problem.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to use a kernel older than what the distro shipped with. Using an older one is likely to break a lot of things.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  You should ask about the actual problem that you face, not how to apply some hypothetical solution (that might be impossible or unhelpful)

Comment: You should ask a new question mentioning the model of your GPU, and the problems you face when installing latest Ubuntu on the computer.

Comment: @pilot6 Thnaks for your comment. I have mentioned the problem here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300031/unable-to-install-an-old-nvidia-driver-in-lubuntu

Comment: @youreagitfornotusinggit Thanks for the comment. I have mentioned the problem here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300031/unable-to-install-an-old-nvidia-driver-in-lubuntu

Comment: @nmath Thanks for your comment. I have mentioned the problem here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300031/unable-to-install-an-old-nvidia-driver-in-lubuntu

Comment: @archisman-panigrahi Thanks for your comment. I have mentioned the problem here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300031/unable-to-install-an-old-nvidia-driver-in-lubuntu

Comment: I wouldn't use a 10.04 kernel, the issue you describe sounds like https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1895905 which in my testing didn't appear before *eoan* / 19.10 & the 5.3 kernel.  I don't test much with nvidia, but did quite a lot up to & including *disco* cycle as I saw issue first on a *disco* (i386) box bumped to *eoan* during *alpha* stage before builds were turned off (for i386, which was a about a week before actual *eoan* release)  You change the `sddm` theme & issue reduces.. and issue only impacts login screen itself.